# Using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS Desktop on same machine?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-pro, error-000539

I'm just trying out ArcGIS Pro for the first time and I had to change my PYTHONPATH to python34

ArcGIS Pro is now working without crashing every time I open the Analysis tab... However now when I try to run a process in ArcMap 10.3.1, I get various python errors; on tools that worked a half hour ago with the same exact data inputs.

Is this a conflict in python versions since ArcGIS 10.3.1 uses 2.7?

Is there a way to have ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS 10.3.1 running simultaneously on the same machine, even though each utilizes a different python version?

[image: Upgrade Metadata tool]

Comment: I have both installed on my PC, no errors. I did not change PYTHONPATH.

Comment: How do you not encounter issues when selecting the Analysis tab in ArcGIS Pro?
It will crash if the PYTHONPATH is not pointed to python34...

Comment: ArcGIS Pro 1.1

I just changed the PYTHONPATH back to C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages
and my processes in ArcMap 10.3.1 are running fine...

Now my ArcGIS Pro is crashing again on Analysis Tab.

Comment: I'll try to reinstall ArcPro 1.1

Comment: Dont think that'll 'fix it'. Im waiting to hear from a co-worker on this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll try to explain this the best I can so hopefully you can move forward.
The short answer is, if your **PYTHONPATH** is pointing at an actual version of Python, when a product loads up and needs Python it's going to see this directory. In the case of ArcGIS Pro (64bit, using Python 3.4) and ArcMap (32bit, using Python 2.7)... well the use of PYTHONPATH and pointing to the 'wrong' version of Python is going to break the application. (wrong and break is based on where you're pointing at and what app you load) Ie. Your system wide level of saying "import these modules for any/all versions of Python!" is what confuses/breaks ArcGIS.

[How to use PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492) explains PYTHONPATH better than I can.

The question is why do you need the PYTHONPATH? What application wants this? If you take a look here `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages` you'll see **.pth** files. These are used at the particular Python version to point at required modules. Could you make use of a .PTH for the particular version of Python that has required you to plug in the PYTHONPATH to begin with?

Comment: Not sure what happened, I just reinstalled ArcPro and reset the PYTHONPATH to the default for ArcGIS 10.3.1
Both seem to be working now again... Time will tell?

Comment: what do you mean default? ArcGIS install doesnt set a PYTHONPATH

Comment: It certainly did for me... 
PYTHONPATH - C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages